# Need SQL Query Help: How to Search and Replace Specific Text LIKE x AND NOT LIKE xx

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-like

and thanks in advance for any help. I'm working on fixing all broken links in a massive WordPress multisite database and need some help writing an SQL query to run via PHP MyAdmin. I've searched, but can't the perfect solution...

PROBLEM: We have more than a thousand broken links that start with http:/ instead of http://

CHALLENGE: The following would result in numerous links starting with http:///

```
    UPDATE wp_1_posts
    SET post_content = replace (post_content, 
    'http:/', 
    'http://');
```

PROCESS: I want to write a query to SELECT all these links first, so I can review them to ensure I don't do any damage when replacing the text string. Downloading a db dump and doing a manual S&R is not an option since we're talking about a multi-gigabyte database.

I thought something like this would work...

```
    SELECT * FROM wp_1_posts
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%http:/%'
    AND WHERE post_content NOT LIKE '%http://%'
```

But that just throws a syntax error. Am I even close?

QUESTION #1: How can I find all instances of "http:/" without returning all "http://" instances in the query results.

QUESTION #2: How might I safely fix all instances of "http:/" without affecting any "http://" strings.

FYI: I'll admit I know just enough about this to be dangerous, and I am not familiar with regular expressions. at. all. That's why I'm turning to you for help. Thanks again!

Comment: The second `WHERE` should be removed. You have one where clause with multiple conditions. This is basic SQL syntax, and not specific to MySQL, let alone wordpress, MyAdmin or multisite.

Comment: One possible solution could be to first update `http://` to `http:/`. After that, you can replace `http:/` with `http://` again. This is an easy solution if you're not experienced with regex and most of the urls are incorrect anyway. If only 10 in a million are wrong, then this is not the right way, since you will first break all of them.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you for the prompt reply! The following returned and empty result set, though the app I used to find bad links identified numerous http:/ urls... 

SELECT *
FROM wp_1_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '%http:/%'
AND post_content NOT LIKE '%http://%'

Comment: Is not the 'http...' at the start of the contents of the string? If so no need to put `%` before the 'http' as that will slow down the search considerably. `LIKE 'http://%'` is better if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, in MYSQL:

```
UPDATE wp_1_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,'http:/', 'http://') 
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'http:/[^/]'
```